# How to return a value from event listener's callback function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Here's a bit about function:

This function takes the file object from html input tag and according to the quality value passed it compresses the image on the browser itself and this compressed image is used to upload to the server. the problem here is that I am not able to return the compressed file object which is generated inside a callback function passed into eventlistner in the following code.

Here's the function definition:

```
function compress_image_file(image_file_object, quality) {
  const file = image_file_object;
  const file_name = file.name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");

  var data_url = '';

  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  if (reader.readyState == 2) {
    console.log('readyState = 2');
  }

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    //convert file to base 64 string
    data_url = reader.result;

    //create a temp image
    image = new Image();
    image.src = data_url;

    //calculate new sizes for the new image
    new_width = image.width * quality / 100;
    new_height = image.height * quality / 100;



    //create a canvas
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    //setting canvas size
    canvas.width = new_width;
    canvas.height = new_height;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, new_width, new_height);

    //convert new image to data url
    newDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

    //convert data url  to file
    var arr = newDataUrl.split(',');
    var mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
    var ext = '.' + mime.split('/')[1];
    //decode the base-64 image
    var bstr = atob(arr[1]);

    var n = bstr.length;

    var u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

    while (n--) {
      u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }

    var new_file = new File([u8arr], file_name + ext, { type: mime });


  })

  // I am trying to return the value of new_file

}
```

here is how I want to implement the above function

```
var file_object = input.files[0]
var new_file = compress_image_file(file_object, 50)

console.log(new_file) // undefined
```

instead of undefined how can I get the file object in var new_file

Comment: Callbacks don't return values - that's not their purpose. They are called when something happens and then the callbacks do something else. What would they be returning the value to? This is an "how do I do asynchronous programming" question.

Comment: Thank you @Adam for your answer